# what does plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() mean?

Tags: python, matplotlib

what does plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() mean? what is the syntax of the code, it just returns figure() and a,b are not the same

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

a=plt.gcf()

b=matplotlib.figure.Figure()
c=matplotlib.pyplot.figure
print(a==c)                       #returns False
print(a==b)                        #returns False
```